# Como apagar uma pasta inteira em C/C++

Tags: c++

Estou tentando fazer um pequeno "clear" de arquivos temporarios, mais precisamente das seguintes pastas "temp", "%temp%", "prefetch", o problema está sendo na hora de especificar o que é para apagar,ja que eu quero apagar tudo que esta dentro das pastas, ja tentei as seguintes funções: `std::filesystem::remove_all("C:\Windows\Temp");`, `remove("C:\Windows\Temp")` e ambas não funcionaram pelo fato de pelo o que eu entendi deletarem apenas um arquivo especifivo. Obs: Comecei a estudar C++ a pouco tempo.

Codigo abaixo

```cpp
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
    //title for the cmd
    system("title Temporary Files / Logs Cleaner\n");

    //color changer (background and text)
    system("color 0C");
    
    std::cout << "{+} - WARNING: This will not compromise you computer, it will only delete TEMPORARY files that will not be used more. \n";
    system("\npause");


    std::cout << "\n{+} -- By pressing another key this progam will delete the following folders: Temp, %temp% and Prefetch.\n";
    system("\npause");

    std::cout << "\n{+} --- Deleting files\n";
    std::filesystem::remove_all("C:\Windows\Temp");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: o problema pode ser a barra  unica , tente utilizar  `"C:\\Windows\\Temp"` duas barras

Comment: Consegui resolver mais tive que utilizar uma método diferente de filesystem, FindNextFile etc, é mais complexo e tive q pesquisar bastante mais consegui botar pra funcionar, so falta resolver alguns problemas no codigo como não apagar a pasta %temp% mais de resto funcionou certinho

Comment: @stack.cardoso todas essas funções e a API do Windows aceitam indistintamente a barra invertida e a barra comum

Comment: Tem um exemplo em C com comentários em português no primeiro local a pesquisar: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/win32/fileio/listing-the-files-in-a-directory. Usar outra solução não explica o que estava errado lá. De todo modo considere que são pastas de uso comum e que é natural não conseguir remover todos os arquivos ou mesmo a pasta. Por isso `remove_all()` retorna o número de arquivos removidos em um `uintmax_t`

Comment: Explicando mais: uso compartilhado seria melhor descrição. Sempre pode haver arquivos abertos nessa pasta e você não conseguir apagar. Pode usar um timer e reiniciar, ou tentar outras vezes, mas pode mesmo não dar certo.

Comment: Não conheço bem o sistema Windows. @arfneto pensei que as 2 barras iria ser um escape. Mas pensei errado :/ obg pela informacao.

Comment: @stack.cardoso o primeiro backslash é o "escape". Esses são dois erros do programa do autor: o '\W' e o '\T' em `"C:\Windows\Temp"` . Acho que ele não viu sequer os avisos do compilador. E é super normal não conseguir apagar essas pastas. A todo momento tem arquivos abertos nelas. Por isso `remove_all()` retorna um contador. Se eu tiver tempo vou deixar um exemplo para ele

Comment: Postei um exemplo e uma explicação de porque seu programa dá erro. Claro que foi considerada inútil por alguns aqui :D mas pode te servir de algo

Answer (score 0):

> um pequeno "clear" de arquivos temporarios, mais precisamente das seguintes pastas "temp", "%temp%", "prefetch", o problema está sendo na hora de especificar o que é para apagar,ja que eu quero apagar tudo que esta dentro das pastas

As pastas temporárias do sistema são de uso comum. Arquivos são sempre abertos lá e muitos são de outros processos ou serviços, então pode nem ser saudável apagar coisas lá dentro. Pode corromper coisas lícitas do sistema se seu programa tiver privilégios suficientes para fazer isso.

Pode ser mais esperto deixar isso para um script de login que roda antes de ter sessões abertas na máquina por exemplo. Isso quer dizer: não usar seu programa apontando para essas pastas a qualquer hora

#### Sobre o programa

- Outra coisa a pensar: mudar títulos de janelas no sistema e cores pode enfurecer usuários de seu programa. Em geral ao mudar qualquer coisa como fontes ou cores deve antes salvar os valores em uso e ao final do programa restaurar os valores originais. E espere para fazer isso quando a função principal de seu programa estiver rodando.
- Não use `system()` em um programa `C` ou `C++`. O sistema foi escrito em `C`, `system()` foi escrita em `C` então use o **sistema** para fazer tais mudanças se acha mesmo que precisa disso. Em muitos ambientes chamar `system()` nem é permitido.

```
    std::filesystem::remove_all("C:\Windows\Temp");
```

- Em Windows e Linux pode usar tanto a barra normal quanto a invertida, mas se vai usar a barra invertida em uma string em `C` ou `C++` deve usar DUAS já que a primeira indica que a próxima letra tem um sentido especial, como em ``\t' ou `\n`. Isso quer dizer que seu compilador certamente te avisou de que `\W` e `\T` em seu programa eram sequências inválidas.

Use

```
    std::filesystem::remove_all("C:\\Windows\\Temp");
// ou
    std::filesystem::remove_all("C:/Windows/Temp");
```

- Se precisa mesmo incluir `stdlib.h` ou `locale.h` em um programa `C++` use a convenção: não use o `.h` ao final e inclua um `c` no início, usando `cstdlib` e `clocale` nesse caso. Nesse caso aqui não precisa de nenhum dos dois.

#### Erros acessando pastas do sistema

Se leu até aqui deve imaginar que é bem provável ter uma quantia de arquivos nessas pastas e que você não pode apagar, porque não tem privilégios ou porque estão abertos por outros processos. E claro que ao mesmo tempo em que você tenta apagar tem processos do sistema criando novos arquivos lá dentro.
Programe considerando isso.

### Um exemplo em `C++`

Vou deixar um exemplo bem bobinho mas que pode servir como exemplo para algo como o que quer fazer.

#### uso do exemplo

O programa de exemplo usa a convenção comum do Unix / Linux de esperar a lista de pastas na linha de comando porque é o simples desde os anos 70. Ex: se o programa se chamar `pg.exe`:

```
        pg pasta1 pasa2 pasta3 ... pastaN
```

e um exemplo de execução seria

```
C:\SO_pt>pg \temp \tmp %TEMP% C:\windows\prefetch c:\windows\TEMP
```

Nesse caso tem 5 pastas a apagar. Segue um resultado típico e o código `C++`

**Cuidado ao usar isso como está: é só um exemplo para mostrar como escrever. Se você teclar *Aceito* quer dizer bem isso: lá se vão seus arquivos dessas pastas.**

O trecho abaixo cria 2 pastas, `temp` e `tmp` e cria dois arquivos dentro da segunda, e depois tenta apagar as pastas todas.

```
SO_pt>mkdir \tmp \temp

SO_pt>mkdir \temp\1 \temp\2

SO_pt>dir \t*.*
 O volume na unidade C não tem nome.
 O Número de Série do Volume é 68AE-4AE7

 Pasta de C:\

11/04/2023  02:05    <DIR>          temp
11/04/2023  02:05    <DIR>          tmp
               0 arquivo(s)              0 bytes
               2 pasta(s)   32.102.146.048 bytes disponíveis

SO_pt>dir \temp
 O volume na unidade C não tem nome.
 O Número de Série do Volume é 68AE-4AE7

 Pasta de C:\temp

11/04/2023  02:05    <DIR>          .
11/04/2023  02:05    <DIR>          ..
11/04/2023  02:05    <DIR>          1
11/04/2023  02:05    <DIR>          2
               0 arquivo(s)              0 bytes
               4 pasta(s)   32.102.141.952 bytes disponíveis

pg \tmp \temp %TEMP% C:\Windows\Temp C:\Windows\Prefetch

        5 pastas a remover:
                "\tmp"
                "\temp"
                "C:\Users\SO_pt\AppData\Local\Temp"
                "C:\Windows\Temp"
                "C:\Windows\Prefetch"

Tecle "Aceito" para apagar essas pastas e arquivos: Aceito


        Esvaziando "\tmp":
                removidos 1 arquivos ou pastas
                A pasta foi REMOVIDA
        Esvaziando "\temp":
                removidos 3 arquivos ou pastas
                A pasta foi REMOVIDA
        Esvaziando "C:\Users\SO_pt\AppData\Local\Temp":
                ERRO!:
                remove_all: O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo.: "C:\Users\SO_pt\AppData\Local\Temp"
ERRO:           remove: O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo.: "C:\Users\SO_pt\AppData\Local\Temp\2a62eaf1-7fcf-410f-a274-fe5cd4b8d5f5.tmp"
ERRO:           remove: O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo.: "C:\Users\SO_pt\AppData\Local\Temp\4a3a2043-79a6-430d-a84d-a0c7a46f92e2.tmp"
ERRO:           remove: O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo.: "C:\Users\SO_pt\AppData\Local\Temp\72fc1232-159b-4f64-91d3-8987361b549e.tmp"
ERRO:           remove: O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo.: "C:\Users\SO_pt\AppData\Local\Temp\7db24816-5a68-4896-b47f-036429143a13.tmp"
ERRO:           remove: O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo.: "C:\Users\SO_pt\AppData\Local\Temp\a2bc62aa-9577-4350-b4a4-7848c7e88729.tmp"
ERRO:           remove: O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo.: "C:\Users\SO_pt\AppData\Local\Temp\aab57cf8-5744-449e-a7a1-09a5e80a1ba3.tmp"
ERRO:           remove: O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo.: "C:\Users\SO_pt\AppData\Local\Temp\bab1122b-f7cb-4fc6-9bbb-f258e94df1d6.tmp"
ERRO:           remove: O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo.: "C:\Users\SO_pt\AppData\Local\Temp\c50efdfc-6d9b-40c3-bdc0-7e0f877604d8.tmp"
ERRO:           remove: O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo.: "C:\Users\SO_pt\AppData\Local\Temp\c720a1ca-0cf9-4700-bd7a-862637a2a0c8.tmp"
ERRO:           remove: O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo.: "C:\Users\SO_pt\AppData\Local\Temp\d3d1e902-4464-453c-900a-211f9f8e4668.tmp"
ERRO:           remove: O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo.: "C:\Users\SO_pt\AppData\Local\Temp\e761d32c-2201-44a0-9d65-c62baae65588.tmp"
ERRO:           remove: O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo.: "C:\Users\SO_pt\AppData\Local\Temp\edg691F.tmp"
ERRO:           remove: O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo.: "C:\Users\SO_pt\AppData\Local\Temp\etilqs_9ZcAZUyVPjD3z4z"
ERRO:           remove: O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo.: "C:\Users\SO_pt\AppData\Local\Temp\etilqs_dqz2kqYXhRrzRs2"
ERRO:           remove: O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo.: "C:\Users\SO_pt\AppData\Local\Temp\etilqs_iaXsqz7flBSLPCx"
ERRO:           remove: O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo.: "C:\Users\SO_pt\AppData\Local\Temp\etilqs_TKNe8SJEaRVFktc"
ERRO:           remove: O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo.: "C:\Users\SO_pt\AppData\Local\Temp\FXSAPIDebugLogFile.txt"
ERRO:           remove: O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo.: "C:\Users\SO_pt\AppData\Local\Temp\geColladaModelCacheLock"
ERRO:           remove: O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo.: "C:\Users\SO_pt\AppData\Local\Temp\geIconCacheLock"
ERRO:           remove: O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo.: "C:\Users\SO_pt\AppData\Local\Temp\Spyder3Utility"
        Esvaziando "C:\Windows\Temp":
                ERRO!:
                remove_all: O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo.: "C:\Windows\Temp"
ERRO:           remove: O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo.: "C:\Windows\Temp\DSK-2206-20230410-0142.log"
ERRO:           remove: O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo.: "C:\Windows\Temp\etilqs_7MxTTQceOEZjwYc"
ERRO:           remove: O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo.: "C:\Windows\Temp\etilqs_ljAq1ZG3DvVhFaB"
ERRO:           remove: O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo.: "C:\Windows\Temp\etilqs_Si3f3O9of6cvDtd"
ERRO:           remove: O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo.: "C:\Windows\Temp\etilqs_xj7ZCdbQaX3QetG"
ERRO:           remove: O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo.: "C:\Windows\Temp\etilqs_xJaFrrpKVHanbJD"
ERRO:           remove: O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo.: "C:\Windows\Temp\etilqs_XvgzN64lUo11H82"
ERRO:           remove: O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo.: "C:\Windows\Temp\officeclicktorun.exe_streamserver(20230410014241107C).log"
        "C:\Windows\Prefetch" nao existe

SO_pt>
```

E pode ver que alguns arquivos como esperado, estão abertos por outros processos e assim `remove_all()` vai cancelar e sem tratamento vai cancelar claro o seu programa. O código mostra uma maneira de tratar isso, interceptando o erro e continuando o programa.

Não é um programa de produção e nem tenho tempo para escrever isso. A idéia é que se não der pra apagar a pasta o programa tenta apenas apagar os arquivos comuns que possam existir dentro dela. Só para mostrar uma maneira de percorrer as pastas. Não me preocupei em tentar recursivamente apagar pastas dentro dessas porque é óbvio: basta fazer mais do mesmo.

#### `main`

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) uso();

    std::locale::global(std::locale("pt_BR"));

    const int N = argc - 1;
    if (previsao(N, argv) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "\n\tCancelando\n";
        return 0;
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    // N pastas
    // tenta apagar uma a uma
    auto total = 0;
    auto res = 0;
    for (auto i = 0; i < N; i += 1)
    {
        res = essa_ja_era(argv[1 + i]);
        if ( res < 0)
            // se deu pau tenta dentro da pasta arquivo por 
            // arquivo e soma quantos apagou
            res += cai_pra_dentro(argv[1 + i]);
    }
    return res;
}
```

- `previsao()` retorna `-1` se o usuário não confirmar que vai apagar as pastas na lista que ele acabou de ver.
- `essa_ja_era()` apaga a pasta com tudo que tem dentro inclusive outras pastas, e retorna o total de arquivos afetados. Ou `-1` se der erro.
- Em caso de erro `cai_para_dentro()` tenta apagar todos os arquivos comuns que existam nessa pasta.

#### O programa completo

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <string>

using std::filesystem::exists;
using std::filesystem::path;
using std::filesystem::remove_all;
using std::string;
using dir_it = std::filesystem::directory_iterator;

void uso();
int  previsao(auto argc, char* argv[]);
int essa_ja_era(const char*);
int cai_pra_dentro(const char*);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) uso();

    std::locale::global(std::locale("pt_BR"));

    const int N = argc - 1;
    if (previsao(N, argv) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "\n\tCancelando\n";
        return 0;
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    // N pastas
    // tenta apagar uma a uma
    auto total = 0;
    auto res = 0;
    for (auto i = 0; i < N; i += 1)
    {
        res = essa_ja_era(argv[1 + i]);
        if ( res < 0)
            // se deu pau tenta dentro da pasta arquivo por 
            // arquivo e soma quantos apagou
            res += cai_pra_dentro(argv[1 + i]);
    }
    return res;
}

void uso() {
    std::cout << "Use: \"programa pasta1 pasta2 ... pastaN\"\n";
    std::exit(1);  // sem argumentos nada a fazer
}

int previsao(auto N, char* argv[]) {
        std::cout << "\n\t" << N << " pastas a remover:\n";
        for (auto i = 0; i < N; i += 1) {
                std::cout << "\t\t\"" << argv[1 + i] << "\"\n";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
        std::cout << "Tecle \"Aceito\" para apagar essas pastas e arquivos: ";
        string valor;
        std::cin >> valor;
        if (valor != "Aceito") return -1;
        return 0;
}

int essa_ja_era(const char* pasta) {
    if (not exists(pasta)) {
        std::cout << "\t\"" << pasta << "\" nao existe\n";
        return 0;
    }
    std::cout << "\tEsvaziando \"" << pasta << "\":\n";
    auto res = 0;
    try
    {
        res = (int) remove_all(pasta);
    }
    catch ( std::filesystem::filesystem_error const& ex)
    {
        std::cout << "\t\tERRO!:\n\t\t"
            <<  ex.what() << '\n';
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "\t\tremovidos " << res << " arquivos ou pastas\n";
    if (exists(pasta))
        std::cout << "\t\tA pasta não foi removida\n";
    else
        std::cout << "\t\tA pasta foi REMOVIDA\n";
    return res;
}

int cai_pra_dentro(const char* pasta) {
        auto total = 0;
        for (auto const& nome: dir_it{pasta}) {
                auto res = 0;
                if ( std::filesystem::is_regular_file(nome))
                try {
                        res = remove(nome);
                } catch (std::filesystem::filesystem_error const& ex) {
                        std::cout << "ERRO:\t\t" << ex.what() << '\n';
                }
                if (res) total += 1;  // se removeu conta esse
        }
        return total;
}
```

Não vou explicar mais detalhes. pergunte nos comentários se tiver alguma questão.
Essa é a parte importante:

```
    try
    {
        res = (int) remove_all(pasta);
    }
    catch ( std::filesystem::filesystem_error const& ex)
    {
        std::cout << "\t\tERRO!:\n\t\t"
            <<  ex.what() << '\n';
        return -1;
    }
```

Um `try` envolve a chamada a `remove_all()` porque se der erro e se for no sistema de arquivos é para mostrar e continuar o programa...

Comment: Ah o clubinho de vigilantes do SO pt :D então minha resposta que vai direto ao assunto, mostra os problemas no programa original e tem um exemplo completo em C++ comentado e com a saída da execução é inútil. Claro, Claro que é.

Comment: Hoje vejo que já são 4 votos em 2 dias para essa resposta como inútil. Imagino que os zelosos usuários que viram essa resposta de pouca qualidade e a marcaram assim não tenham tempo para escrever algo que seria certamente muito melhor. Pena. Eu poderia aprender com eles.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, so tinha visto agora e botei em pratica e por incrível que parece com uns 40 minutos estudando esse forma eu consegui fazer o codigo apagar, eu ja tinha feito um a 1 semana atras mais utilizei FindFileNext etc, deu muuuito trabalho mais funcionou pra ambas as pastas, essa forma que você passou é bem mais simples e deixou o codigo mais entendivel!

Comment: Não entendo porque a galera marca as coisas com o voto pra baixo, mais curti muito a resposta que você colocou :D

Comment: o lance dos votos negativos eu acho que tem a ver mais com _quem_ do que com _o que_  tem na resposta. Em geral qualquer coisa que eu poste vem com uns 3 ou 4 votos negativos em minutos. E qualquer coisa que certos usuários postam já vem com uns tantos a favor, mesmo que o conteúdo não seja assim uma beleza...

Comment: `std::filesystem` é muito útil e tem ainda a vantagem de rodar em Linux e Windows. E você tem razão, é mais legível o código. No seu caso é importante saber que em muitos casos não vai mesmo conseguir apagar tudo, muito menos a pasta, e é normal. Por isso um `try` é importante pra manter o programa rodando